# algorithm2e and Beamer - How to make algorithms wider with smaller font?

Tags: beamer, algorithms, algorithm2e, width

I would like to make the `algorithm2e` environments wider in a `beamer` document. Indeed I must you a `\scalebox` to see all of my algorithm. Is there a way to have wider algorithms with smaller size font than the standard text  **WITHOUT using scalebox** ? The size in my M(merely not)WE looks good for me.

### OUTPUT

[image]

### M(merely not)WE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[french]{babel}

    \usepackage[french, lined]{algorithm2e}

    \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}


\begin{document}

\frame{
    \frametitle{Premier algorithme}

\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \Begin{
        \ForEach{Case $C$ de la grille $G$}{
            \If{$| poss(C) | \geq 2$}{
                \ForEach{$p \in poss(C)$}{
                    $isole \leftarrow Vrai$
                    \\
                    \ForEach{Bloc $B$ contenant la case $C$}{
                        \ForEach{Case $C_B \neq C$ du bloc $B$}{
                            \If{$p \in poss(C_B)$}{
                                $isole \leftarrow Faux$
                                \\
                                Ne plus tester d'autres cases $C_B$.
                            }
                        }
                        \If{$isole = Vrai$}{
                            $g_{ij} \leftarrow \{ p \}$ où $(i,j) = coord(C)$
                            \\
                            $G \leftarrow \texttt{MettreAJour}(G)$
                            \\
                            Ne plus tester les blocs $B$ contenant $C$
                        }
                    }
                    \If{$isole = Vrai$}{
                        Ne plus tester les possibilités restantes de la case $C$
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        \Return $G$
    }
\end{algorithm}
}   
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is obvious... :)

You're scaling down the regularly allowed `\textwidth` algorithm to 65% of its original size. Since this scaling is done *after* setting the algorithm, the traditional line breaks still remain, making it seem like the algorithm is "cut short" on the right hand side.

Here's an abbreviated version of your algorithm showing the traditional line break:

[image]

Here's an update, where the algorithm is *first* set in a `minipage` of width `1.53846\textwidth`, which makes `\scalebox{0.65}` result in a box of width `\textwidth` (that is, 1.53846 x 0.65 ~ 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Premier algorithme}

  \scalebox{0.65}{%
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \Begin{
      \ForEach{Case $C$ de la grille $G$}{
        \If{$| poss(C) | \geq 2$}{
          \ForEach{$p \in poss(C)$}{
            $isole \leftarrow Vrai$
            \If{$isole = Vrai$}{
              Ne plus tester les possibilités restantes de la case $C$
            }
          }
        }
      }
      \Return $G$
    }
  \end{algorithm}}
\end{frame}   

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Premier algorithme}

  \scalebox{0.65}{\begin{minipage}{1.53846\textwidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \Begin{
      \ForEach{Case $C$ de la grille $G$}{
        \If{$| poss(C) | \geq 2$}{
          \ForEach{$p \in poss(C)$}{
            $isole \leftarrow Vrai$
            \If{$isole = Vrai$}{
              Ne plus tester les possibilités restantes de la case $C$
            }
          }
        }
      }
      \Return $G$
    }
  \end{algorithm}%
  \end{minipage}}
\end{frame}   

\end{document}
```

If you wish to retain the natural look of the algorithm without using `\scalebox`, [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides `\SetAlFnt{<font>}` where you can set the font size (or other font formatting options) for the entire algorithm. For example, `\SetAlFnt{\footnotesize}` will decrease the font size to `\footnotesize`.

Comment: I know that. I've put in my question. The problem is that other algorithms are longer. So I would like to have a wider algorithm together with a smaller size for font in algorithms WITHOUT using scalebox.

Comment: Perhaps you're after `\SetAlFnt`, which you can use to set the font size of the algorithm. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: That will do the job (I hope).

Comment: @projetmbc: In addition to setting the font, perhaps you can modify the indent as well. This is done using `\SetInd{<before rule>}{<after rule>}`. Default is `\SetInd{0.5em}{1em}`.

Comment: Is it christmas ? Thanks for this 2nd indication. :-)